# Change line ends shape type to square on chart in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Trying to add a runway on a chart in vb.net. My code below works but getting a line with rounded ends. just wondering if I could change its appearance to squared ends so it can look more like a runway. Coordinates modified for simplicity.

`Me.Chart2.Series.Add("RWY")`
`Me.Chart2.Series("RWY").Color = Color.DarkBlue`
`Me.Chart2.Series("RWY").ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line`
`Me.Chart2.Series("RWY").BorderWidth = 10`
`Chart2.Series("RWY").Points.AddXY(0,0)`
`Chart2.Series("RWY").Points.AddXY(3000,3000)`